# How to create a inherit class for different types of actions in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, model-view-controller, model

I am busy with making a chat app in Swift. I have a create a model of `Conversation`. This model will have two parameters for now: `message` (String) and `isSender` (Bool). If isSender is true, the message will appear at the right side of the view.

For most of the conversation objects I would like to have a certain action that should be called. By creating a new object, I want to tell it's type of conversation action, so I can determine what kind of action is linked to the question/message. Actions can be like, ask for gps permission or to show something else depending on a bool (yes or no).

I thought to create multiple classes that inherits from the model class. In my example for asking permission for gps and for now a Boolean value.

Adding a new parameter, so I can choose the type of action and for some actions an optional closure.

But I am struggling with getting the right result and structure. How can I fix this?

My model class looks like this:

```
class Conversation: NSObject {

    var message: String?
    var isSender: Bool?

    required init(message: String?, isSender: Bool?) {
        self.message = message
        self.isSender = isSender
    }

}



class gpsPermission: Conversation {

    var hasPermission: Bool?

    func askPermissionForGPS() -> Bool {
        print("Permission for GPS \(hasPermission)")
        return hasPermission!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think about it that way:

Base message - generic and contains only common props.

```
// Sender enum (More readable)
enum MessageSender {
    case me
    case counterparty
}

// Message class
class Message {
    let text: String
    let sender: MessageSender

    required init(with text: String, sender: MessageSender) {
        self.text = text
        self.sender = sender
    }
}

let message = Message(with: "Hi there", sender: .me)
```

Subclass messages - permission for example:

```
// Permission Type
enum PermissionType {
    case location
    case contacts
    case notifications
}

// Permission Message
class PermissionMessage: Message {

    let permissionType: PermissionType
    var permissionGiven = false

    required init(with text: String, sender: MessageSender, permission: PermissionType) {
        self.permissionType = permission
        super.init(with: text, sender: sender)
    }

    required init(with text: String, sender: MessageSender) {
        fatalError("Permission type must be provided")
    }
}

let permissionMessage = PermissionMessage(with: "requesting location", sender: .me, permission: .location)
```

Model must not contain control logic inside it. only trigger UI changes and be changed by it.

**EDIT:**
About requesting permissions from the user and informing model object. 
IMO, this logic should be totally separated from the model (Message, PermissionMessage, ...). I would recommend that u implement it in a separate stateless manager / controller, send the function a completion handler - something like this:

```
let contactsPermission = PermissionMessage(with: "requesting contact access", sender: .me, permission: .contacts)
PermissionManager.requestContactsPermission {
    contactsPermission.permissionGiven = true
}

class PermissionManager {
    static func requestContactsPermission(withCompletion successHandler: ()->()) {

        var approved = false
        /*
         Request contact permission
         When done set 'approved' to true, call handler
         */

        if approved {
            successHandler()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank your for your code example. Although it's good to follow, I have some questions about the above code.  So we've two types now, one to display a basic message `Message()` and one for asking permission `PermissionMessage()`. As you indicate, no logic of the code must be done within the class. I understand, but how can I now use the `PermissionMessage` subclass to ask permission for example the GPS location of the user, because there is no function to do this. Now I can only create a new Model with one extra param `permission`.

Comment: >> Is it possible to create an example function for how I can do something depending on the enum type of the permission? Should I create a separate Swift file for handling for example the location permission and call that function using a switch to check which type of enum is used? Or is this not the way you pointed to. Hope you can help me a further. Thanks in advance. @DanielH

Comment: @Caspert, i edited my answer to your request. I hope you get the general idea :-)

Comment: So if I understand it correct, sorry if not, I am trying to get it. When I would like to add a message for asking permission, I should create the Model PermissionMessage and also set the permissionGiven bool to true manually. So set the `permissionGiven` to true can be done by using a button for example? I think `permissionMessage.permissionGiven` should be `contactsPermission.permissionGiven`? Also I can't see where you use that variable in the above script further to determine some action.

Comment: You can use a button - Permission trigger is totally depends on your choice.
My bad - fixed permissionMessage to contactsPermission.
I tried  to help and gave you the gist of the idea. The rest of the code logic is up to you :-)

Comment: The driven action (after the boolean is set) is up to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158112/discussion-between-danielh-and-caspert).